# fetch price from the Android store based on the product_id

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In my application I am using in app billing (Android).

I want to fetch price from the Android market based on the product_id.

please show me a way to do that.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Android because of some Internal Security Issues.